# Show .png image in a JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing

I am a little stuck.  Why wont this work?  I just get a error saying:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
>
> Exception in thread "main"

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowPNG extends JFrame
{    

  public void main(String arg) 
  { 
    if (arg == null ) {
        arg = "C:/Eclipse/workspace/ShowPNG/bin/a.png";
    }      
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    panel.setSize(500,640);
    panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN); 
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(arg); 
    JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
    label.setIcon(icon); 
    panel.add(label);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel); 
    this.setVisible(true);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: s/public void main(String arg)/public **static** void main(String **[]** arg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

main needs to be static, and must have an argument of String[], not String.

To fix this stick everything in a constructor, such as

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowPNG extends JFrame
{    
  private ShowPNG(String arg){
      if (arg == null ) {
        arg = "C:/Eclipse/workspace/ShowPNG/bin/a.png";
    }      
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    panel.setSize(500,640);
    panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN); 
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(arg); 
    JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
    label.setIcon(icon); 
    panel.add(label);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel); 
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ShowPNG(args.length == 0 ? null : args[0]).setVisible(true); 
  }
}
```

Comment: RD was right, that the main method was incorrect but Leo Izen gets this answer because he provided all the code. This code didn't quite work though... you have to use this.setSize on the JFrame to get it to resize correctly. thanks anyway!  See my post below for the actual answer.

Comment: You could always use Frame.pack();

Answer (score 11):

Your main method should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 4):

This was the finished code:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  

@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
public class ShowPNG extends JFrame {   

  public ShowPNG(String argx) { 
    if ( argx == null ) {
      argx = "a.png";
 }   
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
 this.setSize(500,640);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();  
    //panel.setSize(500,640);
    panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);  
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(argx);  
    JLabel label = new JLabel();  
    label.setIcon(icon);  
    panel.add(label); 
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);    
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
      new ShowPNG(args.length == 0 ? null : args[0]).setVisible(true);
  } 

}
```

Comment: Change `this.setSize(500,640);
..
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);` for `.. this.getContentPane().add(panel); this.pack();`