# Add an image to a Swing application

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I'm fairly new to Java and still in the process of learning it, but I want to display an image inside of a JFrame. I've searched everywhere for an answer, however I haven't come across anything useful yet, I have a character class that keeps track of the X and Y coordinates, as well as whether or not you have a key pressed. Here is the code for the character's class if it would help any.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Char {

    private String Char = "Char.png";
    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Image image;

    public Char() {
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(Char));
        image = ii.getImage();
        x = 40;
        y = 60;
    }

    public void move() {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -1;
            System.out.println("Left arrow key down.");
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 1;
            System.out.println("Right arrow key down.");
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = -1;
            System.out.println("Up arrow key down.");
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 1;
            System.out.println("Down arrow key down.");
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
            System.out.println("Left arrow key up.");
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
            System.out.println("Right arrow key up.");
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 0;
            System.out.println("Up arrow key up.");
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 0;
            System.out.println("Down arrow key up.");
        }
    }
}
```

The Board class is supposed to use the getImage method inside of the Char class and draw the image, but I seem to get the error at this line of code here:

```
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(Char));
    image = ii.getImage();
```

Comment: What error is it, exactly, that you are getting at those lines?

Comment: Please include the stacktrace. Your URI is probably wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160904/show-png-image-in-a-jframe

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
 at Game.Char.<init>(Char.java:26)
 at Game.Board.<init>(Board.java:35)
 at Game.Game.<init>(Game.java:9)
 at Game.Game.main(Game.java:20)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is located at within the root position of the class path or the root path of the Jar if it's packaged as one

Comment: Try adding "/" to the start of the path ("/Char.png")

Comment: Made the error go away and my JFrame came up. But the image didn't display.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that that the image is been painted. You can try & output the image dimensions (System.out.println(ii.getIconWidth()+"x"+ii.getIconHeight());) after it is loaded to make sure it has loaded properly

Comment: I'm painting it in the Board class. And I'll try that. Should help.

Comment: Well, it printed back 16x16. That was the dimensions I set. So it's loading correctly. It's just not displaying. If it would help, I could post my Board class. It's what paints it. The problem may be it's not painting it correctly.

Comment: @LoganStiltner okay. Firstly, it appears that we've answered your original question, now you have new problem. The code you've provided won't tell us what's wrong. You need to accept the question that best heled you (if there was one) & raise a new question with the relevant code. Comments is not the best forum for trying to solve your problems, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do this:

```
//If the image is inside de classpath
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/image"));

//If the image outside de classpath
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("/path/to/image"); //i.e. C:\\images\\x.png
```

Comment: Just tried. Gave me this. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
 at Game.Char.<init>(Char.java:26)
 at Game.Board.<init>(Board.java:35)
 at Game.Game.<init>(Game.java:9)
 at Game.Game.main(Game.java:20)

Comment: Exactly where is the image file inside the packages or in external folder?

Comment: Uhm, I'm using Eclipse. It's located inside the bin folder.

Comment: Then you can use: ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("image.XXX");

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
    this.getClass()  with thenameofyourclass.class

If your class name is Craft (Zetcode) replace this.getClass() with Craft.class
and with Char.png directly next to the .java file. It will work