# How to load an image in JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, png, jpanel

I have a PNG image and I want to use it as a brush.

I want to paint something to `JPanel`.

How to load an image to use as a brush for `JPanel`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com), the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [stackoverflow question checklist](http://tinyurl.com/so-list), rephrase your question, showing us what you have tried and describe the problems you are facing. I am sure we'll help you out, than.

Comment: `TexturePaint` might be a useful search term.

Comment: 1) This breaks down to two questions a) "How to load an image?" b) "How to draw an image to a panel?" 2) The answer to (a) can generally be found in `ImageIO.read(..)` 3) Do you want to use the image as the BG for the panel, or simply show it in a panel?  If 'show' - use a `JLabel(ImageIcon(Image))`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160904/show-png-image-in-a-jframe

Comment: As an aside, what DYM by 'brush'?  Is this a 'paint application'?

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), for a simple understanding of the topic :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Image image = new ImageIcon("C:/images/image.png").getImage();
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(imageToPaint, 
            (desired x location), (desired y location), null);
    }
};
```

Comment: -1 do not override `paint` and do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @user1329572 Besides, he said he wants to use the image as "brush". This implies he would like to use a canvas to draw graphics, and using *paint* is the most... canvasy way to display an image.

Comment: No no no @JesusPlusPlus, paint method is not used for painting such a thingy. Always override `paintComponent()` for such a task. `paint()` is used only when you need to change the state of the `Graphics` object, so that, along with the contents of the said component, it's border as well as children can reciprocate with that changed state of the `Graphics` object.

Comment: @GagandeepBali Always good to learn something new, I changed my answer. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus : Happy to know that, KEEP SMILING :-) . I had negated my downvote, though since my daily limit is gone, I am not sure, if did worked or not, though I will again try tomorrow, when the vote meter will be refilled by stackoverflow again :-). Now the answer is providing valuable information with regard to the issue. Just make sure, that while overriding a method, keep the **Access Specifier** same, as much as possible, like it's `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` :-)